# How to change Text of button in FileUpload control and set value to textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Hi I want to upload file using c# but want to display as below image.

[image]

1. I want to change the text of button from default “Browse” to “Upload”.
2. When User return to this page I want to show image name he/she previously upload in textbox.

After some search I found its not possible to edit button name and set value for textbox.

So I developed below coding.

**.ASPX**

```
 <input runat="server" id="File1" type="file" style=" visibility:hidden;" />
                      <input id="Text1" type="text" runat="server" />
                      <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="fireFileClick()" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
```

**Js**

```
function fireFileClick() {
            var objfile = document.getElementById("<%= File1.ClientID %>");
            objfile.click();


            var objTextBox = document.getElementById("<%= Text1.ClientID %>");
            objTextBox.value = objfile.value;
        }
```

**.cs**

```
private void SetPicture()
{
string strFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string strExtnt = strFileName.Substring(strFileName.LastIndexOf('.') + 1).ToUpper();
            System.Drawing.Image UploadedImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(File1.PostedFile.InputStream);
            float UploadedImageWidth = UploadedImage.PhysicalDimension.Width;
            float UploadedImageHeight = UploadedImage.PhysicalDimension.Height;
            if (UploadedImageWidth < 185 && UploadedImageHeight < 51)
            {
}
}
```

The problem is in .CS im not getting file name and path. the variable strFileName , strExtnt  is returning empty. some body guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

**.Aspx**:

```
<input id="File1" type="file" runat="server" style="visibility: hidden"
    onchange="this.form.submit();" />
<input id="Button2" type="button" onclick="fireFileClick();" value="Upload" />
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function fireFileClick() {
    document.getElementById("<%= File1.ClientID %>").click();
}
```

**.cs**: The same as yours.

*Note: feel free to change the way you submit the form in JavaScript, I just used the fastest way. The form will be submitted after file choice by the user.*

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: [ref](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)
Basically uses two input controls, hides the actual input upload control, and applies styling to the non-file upload control.  Awesome sauce!

Answer (score 0):

The browse button is not editable to keep things simple. Why not just say something like:

```
 UPLOAD:
|--------|
| Browse |
|--------|
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34886043)

Answer (score -1):

using two js files http://the-echoplex.net/demos/upload-file/file-upload.js and http://the-echoplex.net/demos/upload-file/jelly/min.js .And add the file-upload.css file.Your sample
aspx file is,

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>  
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
 <script src="script/jelly.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
   <style type="text/css">  
 /****************** Start page styles ********************************************/  
 body {  
      background: #DFA01B;  
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;  
      font-size: 11px;  
      }  
 #wrap {  
      max-width: 600px;  
      margin: 30px auto;  
      background: #fff;  
      border: 4px solid #FFD16F;  
      -moz-border-radius: 15px;  
      -webkit-border-radius: 15px;  
      border-radius: 15px;  
      padding: 20px;  
   }  
 .field {   
      padding: 0 0 1em;   
      }  
 </style>  
 <head runat="server">  
   <title></title>  
 </head>  
 <body>  
   <form id="form1" runat="server">  
   <div id="wrap">  
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="post">  
      <div class="field">  
           <label class="file-upload">  
                <span><strong>Put YOUR TEXT</strong></span>  
                <%--<input type="file" name="uploadfile" onclintclick="test_load()" />--%>  
       <asp:FileUpload  
         ID="FileUpload1" name="uploadfile" runat="server"   
       ondatabinding="FileUpload1_DataBinding" />  
           </label>  
      </div>  
 </form>  
 </div><!--/ wrap -->  
   <script src="script/file-upload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
   </form>  
 </body>  
 </html>
```

and CSS file,

```
body {
}
/* 

    As this stylesheet is lazy loaded these styles only apply if JavaScript is enabled

*/  
.file-upload {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;

    /* Cosmetics */
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #2FA2FF;
    background: #6FBEFF;

    /* Nice if your browser can do it */
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 4px;
    }

.file-upload:hover { 
    background: #2FA2FF; 
    }

.file-upload.focus { 
    outline: 2px solid yellow;
    }

.file-upload input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 70px;

    /* Loses tab index in webkit if width is set to 0 */
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    }

.file-upload strong { 
    font: normal 1.75em arial,sans-serif; 
    }   

.file-upload span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;

    /* Adjust button text vertical alignment */
    padding-top: .45em;
    }

/* Adjust the button size */    
.file-upload { height: 3em; }
.file-upload,
.file-upload span { width: 14em; }  

.file-upload-status {
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 7px 11px;
    font-weight: bold;  
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #888;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border: 3px solid #ddd;
    }
```

you can download sample project at [changedfileuploadbutton text](http://kuttyrajesh.blogspot.in/2016/02/changing-fileuplaod-control-text-in.html)